# Check if there is a duplicate item in FormGroups field in Angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach

While saving all my grid rows, I need to check whether there is a duplicate for a specific column field

```
 (this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).controls.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.value.attributeDisplayName);       
  });
```

I need to stop the form from submission by showing an alert or something similar when there is a duplicate value for `attributeDisplayName`. How can I check that in the current forEach loop. Thanks

I am using kendo angular components in my HTML markup and I am not using form tag. Below is an example for column declaration

```
  <kendo-grid-column field="attributeDisplayName" title="CUSTOM FIELD LABEL" width="190">  
        <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" >          
          <input ngDefaultControl  class="k-textbox" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)">
          
          <div *ngIf="formGroup.get(column.field).errors && (formGroup.get(column.field).dirty || formGroup.get(column.field).touched)">
                <span style="color:red" class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span>
                <span style="color:red">CUSTOM FIELD LABEL is a required field</span>
                
          </div>

        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Below is FormGroup declartion in .ts file

```
    public formGroup: FormGroup;
    public formGroups: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ items: new FormArray([]) });
    
    public createFormGroup = (dataItem) =>
        new FormGroup({
            atrributeId: new FormControl(dataItem.atrributeId),
            objectType: new FormControl(dataItem.objectType, Validators.required),
            attributeDisplayName: new FormControl(dataItem.attributeDisplayName, Validators.required),     
            dataType: new FormControl(dataItem.dataType, Validators.required),
            inputValues: new FormControl(dataItem.inputValues, [Validators.required,  InputValuesValidator]),
            isGridEligible: new FormControl(dataItem.isGridEligible, Validators.required),
            isInvoiceEligible: new FormControl(dataItem.isInvoiceEligible, Validators.required),
        });
```

An example function where I use this FormGroup

```
    public editRows(grid) {      
      this.isEdited = true;
      let currentRow = 0;
      let rows: any = grid.data.data;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const formGroup = this.createFormGroup(rows[i]);          
        this.formGroup = formGroup;
        (this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).push(formGroup);        
        grid.editRow(currentRow, formGroup, {skipFocus: true});
        currentRow++;
      }      
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking it while submitting, just check it while filling form only and show the error immediately if user has filled duplicate value.

[Working demo here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fklep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

use this function to check duplicacy -

```
checkDuplicacy(event, field: FormControl) {
    let length = this.formGroups.value.items.length;
    let count = 0;
    let controls = (<FormArray>this.formGroups.controls.items).controls;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (
        this.formGroups.value.items[i].attributeDisplayName.toLowerCase() ==
        event.target.value.toLowerCase()
      ) {
        count++;
      }
      if (count > 1) {
        field.markAsTouched();
        field.setValidators((f) => <any>{ duplicateName: true });
        field.updateValueAndValidity();
      } else {
        field.clearValidators();
        field.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        field.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    }
  }
```

And Updated HTML -

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="attributeDisplayName" title="CUSTOM FIELD LABEL" width="190">  
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" >          
  <input ngDefaultControl  class="k-textbox" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" (blur)="checkDuplicacy($event, formGroup.get(column.field))">
  

      <div *ngIf="formGroup.get(column.field).errors && (formGroup.get(column.field).dirty || formGroup.get(column.field).touched)">
            <span style="color:red" class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span>
            <span style="color:red">CUSTOM FIELD LABEL is a required field</span>
            
      </div>
    
      <span *ngIf="formGroup.get(column.field).errors?.duplicateName" style="color:red">
      Duplicate field.</span>
    
    </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using reactive form, so can we write this like a validator and use it in the formgroup declaration for the field, instead of using it onblur()? Please suggest

Comment: @vamsi I think it's not possible (not sure) because, for using the same logic in the custom validator function, we need to access the entire formGroup inside the validator function for getting items value. And entire formGroup can not be passed in validator because we do not have it at the time of declaring formGroup.

Comment: @ShyamJoshi, you can access to the FormArray using control.parent.parent in the vaidator, see my answer

Comment: @Eliseo Ohh, that's really nice. Thanks. Upvoting your answer...

Comment: @ShyamJoshi, I have updated my question for better understanding. I am actually not using <form> tag in my HTML markup, neither any 'index'. So, obliviously when I try to use this code, I am getting error at 'index', saying it is undefined. Any workaround I can do for this? Please suggest.

Comment: Sure, but it will be helpful for me if you can create a stackblitz example with a small working code. I will add my code in that. I don't need complete code, just create a small example with one formArray (items) and one formControl in that.

Comment: Sorry, I am not really sure how can I create stackblitz example as I have many dependencies. You may get a high level idea if you check my updated question. I have added few code blocks for my HTML, TS files. If you can just give me an idea on how can we achieve this without <form> tag or index, that would be very helpful for me

Comment: @vamsi I have updated my answer, kindly check, it should work this way.

Comment: @ShyamJoshi, it worked like a charm!!! Thanks man.

Comment: @vamsi Great!!! Happy coding.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use a validator to check the duplicates. The validator is like

```
  validateUniq(index) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      if (control.value) {

        //search the "formArray"
        const formArray = control.parent
          ? (control.parent.parent as FormArray)
          : null;

        if (formArray) {
          //we create an array with the attributeDisplayNames
          const attributes = formArray.value.map((x) => x.attributeDisplayName);
      
          //only give error if there're duplicate before our
          //control
      
          return attributes.indexOf(control.value)>=0 && 
                 attributes.indexOf(control.value)<index
            ? { duplicateName: true }
            : null;
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

You create the formGroup like -see how you pass the "index"

```
  initFormField() {
    const index = this.items ? this.items.length : 0;
    return this.fb.group({
      attributeDisplayName: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, this.validateUniq(index)],
      ],
    });
  }
```

The problem when we use a Validator over a control is that only is checked when the control changes, so we need make a function checkDuplicacy like @Shyam say -but in this case is more simple:

```
  checkDuplicacy(index) {
    this.items.controls.forEach((x,i)=>{
      if (index!=i)
        (x as FormGroup).get('attributeDisplayName').updateValueAndValidity()
    })
  }
```

The last piece to completate the jigsaw is a function to get the control

```
  getAtributeDisplayNameAt(index: number) {
    return this.items
      ? (this.items.at(index).get('attributeDisplayName') as FormControl)
      : null;
  }
```

And an html like

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroups" novalidate autocomplete="off">
  <div formArrayName="items">
    <div
      *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let index = index"
      [formGroupName]="index"
    >
      <div class="form-control">
        <input
          placeholder="Enter here"
          formControlName="attributeDisplayName" 
          (input)="checkDuplicacy(index)"
        />
        <span
          *ngIf="getAtributeDisplayNameAt(index)?.errors?.duplicateName"
          class="error"
        >
          Duplicate field.</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addFormField()">Add More</button>
</form>
```

See how we call to the function `checkDuplicacy` in the event `input` -you can subscribe also to the valueChange of the control

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxpkd6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)